# server core 2008 command

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-core, compression

I want to extract a zip file on [Server Core 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms723891(VS.85).aspx).

Can anyone tell me the command to do so?

Comment: Move this question to one of the other trilogy sites, please. It doesn't belong here.

Comment: I think the question is okay for Serverfault.

Answer (score 2):

You could use this code snippet for a .vbs file (VBScript):

```
Function WindowsUnZip(sUnzipFileName, sUnzipDestination)

  Set oUnzipFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

  If Not oUnzipFSO.FolderExists(sUnzipDestination) Then
    oUnzipFSO.CreateFolder(sUnzipDestination)
  End If

  With CreateObject("Shell.Application")
       .NameSpace(sUnzipDestination).Copyhere .NameSpace(sUnzipFileName).Items
  End With

  Set oUnzipFSO = Nothing

End Function

Call WindowsUnZip("C:\example.zip", "C:\DestinationFolder\")
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no command line utility buit in to unzip files.  When copying files to server core I recommend using makecab and expand.  Or you can install the unzip command line tool of your preference.

Comment: http://www.7-zip.org/ Has a good command line version.

Comment: yeah I've had issues with 7-zip.  Like most open source software, YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

zip.exe and unzip.exe are in my tools folder since 1994 and they work fine in Server Core. I use the versions from [Info-ZIP](http://www.info-zip.org)